# Pandas Expanding Rows According to the Condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Jobs           Total_Duration_(seconds)   #_of_items    Job_divisible
Signature      17000                      100           1
Verification   4000                       20            0
Train          6000                       50            1
Test           3500                       12            1
```

If the work is divisible, I would like to divide the more than 1 hour work into 1 hour sub-jobs. The desired output is:

```
Jobs           Total_Duration_(seconds) #_of_items
Signature_1    3570                     21
Signature_2    3570                     21
Signature_3    3570                     21
Signature_4    3570                     21
Signature_5    2720                     16
Verification   4000                     20
Train_1        3600                     30
Train_2        2400                     20
Test           3500                     12
```

Could you please help me about this?

Comment: How the `3570` and `21` in first row of expected result are achieved?

Comment: If I add 1 more item, because it exceeds 1 hour.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming equal division of the tasks, you can use:

```
n = (np.ceil(df['Total_Duration_(seconds)'].div(3600)).astype(int)
       .where(df['Job_divisible'].eq(1), 1)
    )

out = (df
   .assign(**{'Total_Duration_(seconds)': df['Total_Duration_(seconds)'].div(n),
              '#_of_items': df['#_of_items'].div(n),
              })
   .loc[df.index.repeat(n)]
   .assign(Jobs=lambda d: d['Jobs'].mask((g:=d.groupby('Jobs')).transform('size').gt(1),
                                          df['Jobs'].add('_'+g.cumcount().add(1).astype(str))
                                          )
          )
)
```

Output:

```
           Jobs  Total_Duration_(seconds)  #_of_items  Job_divisible
0   Signature_1                    3400.0        20.0              1
0   Signature_2                    3400.0        20.0              1
0   Signature_3                    3400.0        20.0              1
0   Signature_4                    3400.0        20.0              1
0   Signature_5                    3400.0        20.0              1
1  Verification                    4000.0        20.0              0
2       Train_1                    3000.0        25.0              1
2       Train_2                    3000.0        25.0              1
3          Test                    3500.0        12.0              1
```

Comment: Job "Train" did not produce the desired result.

Comment: @Salih I wrote as preamble of my answer "*Assuming equal division of the tasks*", as you haven't detailed any logic for the division of the time, I made this choice.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
def f(x,y):
    v = 3600
    n = (x // v)
    return np.array(([v] * n + [x-n*v]) if (y == 1) else [x])

def g(x, y, z, w, x1):
    ly = len(y)
    x = [x + '_' + str(i+1) for i in range(ly)] if (ly > 1) else [x]
    
    zaux = z
    z = np.around(z * y / x1, 0)
    z[-1] = zaux - np.sum(z[:-1])
    z = z.astype(int)
    
    return [x, y, z, w] 

(df.transform(lambda x: g(x[0], f(x[1], x[3]), x[2], x[3], x[1]), axis=1)
 .explode(['Jobs','Total_Duration_(seconds)','#_of_items']))
```

Output:

```
           Jobs Total_Duration_(seconds) #_of_items Job_divisible
0   Signature_1                     3600         21             1
0   Signature_2                     3600         21             1
0   Signature_3                     3600         21             1
0   Signature_4                     3600         21             1
0   Signature_5                     2600         16             1
1  Verification                     4000         20             0
2       Train_1                     3600         30             1
2       Train_2                     2400         20             1
3          Test                     3500         12             1
```